# How to get mvc RequestMappingHandlerMapping reference in a service?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My application need to be aware about the mapped URL's since username, or other resource types will dynamically be mapped.

Even been able to get the current mapping, I just can do it on a controller:

```
@Autowired
RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

public void showHandlersMapping() {
    Map<RequestMappingInfo,HandlerMethod> map = handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods();
    Iterator<?> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
    }       
}
```

but I would like to have its reference in `root-context` so other bean could query against it.

How could I accomplish this once the MVC context gets loaded after root-context?

**MY SOLUTION (till now):**

added a @PostConstruct to the Controller where I call apiService.registerHandlersMapping(handlerMapping);

I'm not sure about the drawbacks to this approach but will appreciate any advice.

Comment: How about using [ApplicationContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a different solution also other than the approach that you have mentioned of injecting in the mappings from the web layer to the services layer. There are few design issues here, that you probably have already noted - about the services layer being dependent on the web layer, and I can think of a few ways to mitigate this:

1. Extract the essence of what you require from the handlermappings (say as a simple `Map<String, String>` and inject this alone to the services tier, this way atleast the dependencies are reduced a little.
2. Move the specific services to the web tier, this way the web related dependencies remain in the web tier.

Comment: Anyway I was forced to create a pointless controller to put mapping on service layer, considering that it's a service intented to be used by the weblayer it look ok. But to migrate all like you pointed looks better. The service shoulb be any cache service. so the design at least looks better. yep, makes all sense. thanks